# How to show value of a Multiline TextBox field in DataForm Webpart (2010)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, data-form-web-part, multiline-text-field, append-changes

I have a list called `HOB` which contains `Multiline TextBox` field called as `FacilityComment` with `Append Changes to Existing Text`= `yes`.

And this field contains values which i want to show in  `DataForm Webpart`.
Infact i have bind the field to the webpart but, it shows the `link` not the `value` as shown below :-

[image]

How to show the values of `multiline textbox field` in `DVWP/DFWP`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Marc Anderson's page http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/07/showing-all-versions-of-append-changes-to-existing-text-in-a-data-view-web-part-dvwp/ has the answer you seek. :)